# In welchem Kontext benutzt man "zu Buche schlagen"?

Tags: etymology, vocabulary, standard-german

In welchem Kontext benutzt man "zu Buche schlagen"?

Kann zum Beispiel sagen: "Meine Kenntisse schlagen zu Buche."?

Comment: This question should include more details than have been provided here. Please edit to add the research you have done in your efforts to answer the question, or provide more context.

Comment: @Em1: please **help** the OP with ideas on what specific "research", and what further "details" you need to be happy with the question. For me the question was clear and answerable.

Comment: @Takkat The question is clear and answerable. So is, for instance, "What does *Buch* mean". This question is off-topic as it stands right now. Perhaps I should've linked to our help center, but I just copied the text from our sister site for convenience (because the other two closevoters used the "translation-off-topic" text, which is imho the wrong reason here).

Comment: Since when are questions on the usage of proverbs *off topic*? They usually are very (**very**) hard to look up in dictionaries or resources other than German Lanugage SE ;)

Comment: What is your understanding of it?

Answer (score 2):

Der Ausdruck kommt aus dem Bereich Buchhaltung. Wenn ein Betrag als Einnahme oder als Ausgabe verbucht wurde, wirkt er sich in der Buchhaltung aus, er vergrößert oder verringert die Einnahmen-Seite und letztlich auch die Bilanz. Der Ausdruck kann auch allgemein im übertragenen Sinn verwendet werden, im Sinn von "eine Auswirkung haben auf etwas".

Dein Satz "Meine Kenntnisse schlagen zu Buche" ist nicht gerade optimal. Vielleicht hast du im Sinn: Meine Sprachkenntnisse sind ein Pluspunkt meiner Bewerbung bei der Firma X. Den Ausdruck "schlagen zu Buche" würde ich den Buchhaltern überlassen.

Answer (score 0):

So wie die annähernd synonym verwendete Redewendung "ins Gewicht fallen" kann man auch die aus der Finanzbuchhaltung stammende Wendung "zu Buche schlagen" im übertragenen Sinn verwenden:

> - Doch durch sein moderates Temperament schafft er unbegrenzt Vertrauen und Glaubwürdigkeit; auch im Fernsehen. Und **das schlägt zu Buche**.<sup>[Zeit 33 1985](http://www.zeit.de/1985/33/bonns-tragende-saeule/seite-2)</sup>
> - Dabei **schlägt zu Buche**, daß die engere Vertrautheit mit den Amerikanern künstlerisch effektiver ist und daß die komplexe Hörbarkeit insbesondere der rhythmisch-dynamischen Ausdrucksfülle kaum einmal so exorbitant erreicht wurde daß schließlich Boulez' Intimkenntnis der Musik unserer Zeit ganz neue Aspekte von Mahlers futuristisch-multiplen Klangvisionen aufgedeckt hat.<sup>[Zeit 30 1996](http://www.zeit.de/1996/30/10944)</sup>
> - **Das schlägt zu Buche**, wenn in der Weiterbildungspraxis die Vor- und Nachteile gemeinsam oder getrennten Lernens von Älteren und Jüngeren gegeneinander abgewogen werden.<sup>[T. Ecker et. al, (ed): Bildung der Generationen, p. 140](https://books.google.de/books?id=GZokBAAAQBAJ&lpg=PA140&dq=%22schl%C3%A4gt%20zu%20Buche%22&pg=PA140#v=onepage&q=%22schl%C3%A4gt%20zu%20Buche%22&f=false)</sup>

Allerdings ist diese Wendung nicht sehr verbreitet (anders als beim englischen Pendant<sup>*</sup> *"to take into account"*) und wird vorwiegend, aber nicht ausschließlich, im Kontext einer Finanzlage verwendet.

<sup>*</sup><sub>**Pendant** meint hier den etymologischen Verwandten, nicht die korrekte Übersetzung, nach der ja auch nicht gefragt ist.</sub>

Comment: "to take into account" != "zu Buche schlagen" – Ganz andere Bedeutung: "etwas beachten (bei einer Entscheidung)" vs "bedeutend sein", "ausmachen"

Comment: @Em1: wie kommst du jetzt darauf? Sowohl etymologisch als auch in der Bedeutung im übertragenen Sinn ist da ein sehr enger Zusammenhang. *Account* == *Buch*! Dass die Verwendung im Englischen anders ist, sage ich ja und werde das nicht weiter ausführen, da *off topic* für die Frage, in der es ja ausschließlich um die deutsche Verwendung geht.

Comment: Ich sehe in der Bedeutung keine Überlappung. Und in deiner Antwort erwähnst du nicht, dass es anders ist, sondern suggerierst, dass es das gleiche wäre. Im Wesentlichen steht da: "Im Gegensatz zum englischen Pendant ist die Wendung im Deutschen nicht sehr verbreitet" -> Das sagt aus: Es hat die gleiche Bedeutung. Hat es aber nicht. Ob es etymologisch zusammenhängt, oder Zufall ist, habe ich nicht nachgeschaut. Ist aber auch unerheblich.

Comment: To take into account = etwas berücksichtigen **!=** zu Buche schlagen ~ (have an) impact on the finances.

Comment: @Grantwalzer: siehe Edit.